# Deal with OpenGL context restoration in Android 2.x libgdx?

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx

I read somewhere that OpenGL context can be restored automatically by libgdx framework. And in my case, everything is OK with the real phone 4.0.3. But when I test with Android 2.x, it doesn't work well, just return me a white blank:((.
Isn't it true that i can leave restoring OpenGL context to libgdx? Could you please share your experiences with this? Or libgdx just can't work with Android versions lower than 4.x?( I use Opengl 1.0).

Comment: in fact, opengl context is lost when Android app is restarted. And I don't know how to handle it :(

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1073.  The post is from 2010, and so it talks in about some future features that are now current (TextureAtlas and TextureRegion), and the point of the article is about how dynamically generated textures cannot be automatically managed by libGDX, but implicitly it describes the texture management problem, and how libGDX can be used to solve it in certain cases (basically libGDX needs to know how/where to reload your texture from).

libGDX should work fine on Android 2.x or 4.x.

Are you sure the underlying process is hanging around in both the 4.x and 2.x Android cases?  Texture lossage is only a problem when an Activity exits and the Application stays alive until the Activity is restarted.  If the Application exits, everything is re-initialized.